# Using multiple frontEnd values in a Magento extension

Tags: php, magento

My apologies if this has already been covered, I did some google-fu and I've not found anything like it, so I'll assume it's not a duplicate.

I've written a custom Magento extension, and the client wants to have 2 urls point to it. It's a product registration module, and the config.xml data for the router looks like this:

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <registerform>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Ashmenon_ProductRegister</module>
                    <frontName>product-register</frontName>
                </args>             
            </registerform>
        </routers>      
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Now the client has asked me to also direct '/warranty' to the same module. I've tried adding another `<args>` node inside `<registerform>`, but that doesn't seem to work. URL rewrites (specified within this config.xml) also don't seem to do the trick.

Am I doing something wrong? The documentation and tutorials around Magento extension development (at least the ones I've found so far) are absolute shit, and I'm kinda lost.